# How can I performance tunning on that javascript code? (JQuery selector based)

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I performance tuning in that code

```
var isHighLighted = this.HighlightCell(this.GetOutcomeInList(i), i, "selectedByEditor "+((isCommonChoice) ? "Common" : "") ); 

if (!isHighLighted) {
        isHighLighted = this.HighlightCell(this.GetOutcomeInOtherBetsButton(i), i, "selectedByEditor "+((isCommonChoice) ? "Common" : "") ); 
}

this.HighlightCell(this.GetOutcomeInOthers(i), i, "selectedByEditor "+((isCommonChoice) ? "Common" : "") ); 

var spacialcell = this.GetOutcomeInSpecial(i);
this.HighlightCell(spacialcell, i, "selectedByEditor "+((isCommonChoice) ? "Common" : "") );

if (spacialcell.length > 0) {
        //Özel etkinliklerde kapalı alanları açar
        var eventDetails = $(spacialcell).parent().parent().parent();
        var eventHeaders = $(spacialcell).parent().parent().parent().prev().find('.Expand');

        if (eventDetails.attr('status') != 'expand') {
                eventDetails.show(); $(eventHeaders).not('.Collapse').addClass('Collapse');
                BetFilter.ChangeExpandButtonStatus(this, false);
        }
}
```

That function loop for each editor data in more than 1000 html cell elements. Editor data probably contains between 10 - 100 data. GetOutcomeInList, GetOutcomeInOtherBetsButton functions are jquery selectors returning spesific cells.

Comment: I don't think anyone will willingly re-factor something like that without an explanation what it exactly is you want to improve.. Preferably add some context, maybe some Html where this is run against.

Comment: you're right i added an explanation.

Comment: General way of optimization/tuning: wrap parts into functions and use js profiler (from firebug for Firefox or built-in webinspector in Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

First - don't repeat yourself.

You repeat this expression four times:

```
"selectedByEditor "+((isCommonChoice) ? "Common" : ""
```

also:

```
var eventDetails = $(spacialcell).parent().parent().parent();
var eventHeaders = $(spacialcell).parent().parent().parent().prev().find('.Expand');
```

should be:

```
var eventDetails = $(spacialcell).parent().parent().parent();
var eventHeaders = eventDetails.prev().find('.Expand');
```

Second, there's no need to check that the class doesn't exist before adding it:

```
$(eventHeaders).not('.Collapse').addClass('Collapse');
```

can be:

```
$(eventHeaders).addClass('Collapse');
```

Comment: thanks for your tips. I have completed repeats.There's not visual fining in process...

Comment: @Megawolt in which case you should consider the performance of your `.getOutcomeXXX()` functions.

Comment: each one is like ; `if (this.EditorChoices != null) { return $id(this.EditorChoices[editorIndex].Code + '_' + this.EditorChoices[editorIndex].Outcome);} `. P.S. I think like you. somehow i must reduce the jquery Selector funcitons return {};